# CLLocationManager region monitoring and airplane mode

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I am developing a location dependent feature. The uses case is this:

- User receives data and notifications based on their location.
  Location is actually the city/town they reside in more accurately a
  region based on the city.
- Then they hop on a plane/train and go to another city. I want to
  be able to detect that send them local notification to change
  their location settings and if they accept to start providing them
  data based on the new location i.e. city. Very important to this
  part of the usage is the Airplane mode which is usually turned on
  during the travel and then turned off when the user arrives at
  their destination.

I thought region monitoring will be the perfect technology for that. However there is no way to find out if the user had gone outside the region when using Airplane mode. There will be nor crossing event and I am unable to request the state for the particular region. Also in that case if the app was terminated the system will not wake it up for crossing event because there is not one.

Is there a way to reliably handle that situation.
I also thought a replacement technology for my use case might be the Visit monitoring.

Thanks!

Comment: When the user turns airplane mode off then it should get a new location fix and trigger any appropriate enter/exit region events.

Comment: No callbacks happen.

Comment: Are you using significant location change monitoring?

Comment: Region monitoring